# Angularfire2 prevent new users from being authenticated upon login

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, google-signin

How can I prevent a new user from signing in with google?  Right now I have it where anyone who signs in via google is registered as an authenticated user in my Firebase (Firestore) project.  I tried using credential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser which prevents their info being stored in my users collection but their login info is still generated in authentication.

```
  googleLogin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
  }

  private oAuthLogin(provider) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(credential => {
      if (!credential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        this.updateUserData(credential.user);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't block user creation with client but you can do the following, mark them with some custom attribute to tell which ones you created and which ones where created without admin privileges:

After you create the user. you would set the [custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) on that user via Admin SDK:

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {alloweduser: true}).then(() => {
  // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
  // next time a new one is issued. Since this is created before the user signs in,
  // then when the user signs in, they will have that claim directly.
});
```

You can then enforce access via security rules without having to do any lookup:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "data": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read" : "$user_id === auth.uid && auth.token.alloweduser === true",
        ".write" : "$user_id === auth.uid && auth.token.alloweduser === true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Only users you create are allowed to access content. You can run some recurring script to delete users that tried to sign up from the client SDK.